# Exponent error message

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am receiving the error message "The data types real and smallint are incompatible in the '^' operator" for the following sequence:

```
SELECT b.[CUSIP NUMBER],
       b.[ORIGINAL BALANCE],
       b.[ORIGINAL WA MATURITY],
       b. [PASS THRU RATE],
       b.[ORIGINAL BALANCE] * ( ( b.[PASS THRU RATE] / 12 ) * ( 1 + ( b.[PASS THRU RATE] / 12 )^b.[ORIGINAL WA MATURITY] ) ) / ( 1 + ( b.[PASS THRU RATE] / 12 )^b.[ORIGINAL WA MATURITY] )
FROM   DBO.mbs012013 a,
       dbo.mbs022013 b
WHERE  a.[CUSIP NUMBER] = b.[CUSIP NUMBER]
```

Is there another way to set up the exponent so that I do not receive this error message? Or is there a way to declare the "Original WA Maturity" column as a numeric variable?

For reference: A cusip number is a serial number, original wa maturity is given in months, pass thru rate is given as a percentage (5.5%).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the [`POWER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174276.aspx) function for exponents. `^` is [Bitwise Exclusive OR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190277.aspx)

Comment: Could you show me how to use it? I am having trouble replacing the ^ with the power function

Comment: @user2501239 - Instead of `2^3` (which returns `1` not `8`) use `POWER(2,3)`. Of course your expressions are more complex than that but the principle is the same. Replace `expression1 ^ expression2` with `POWER((expression1 ),(expression2))`